# Enable disable button on text changed in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an application, in which there is a button in search box (like one in itunes).
I want to enable cancel button whenever there is text in text box and disable it when text box is empty.
I tried with text_changed event on textbox with the following code, but it jump over the if condition. Even sender sends me correct values but i am unable to put it into if else.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sender.ToString()))
        {
            btn_cancel.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            btn_cancel.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple solution.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Of course, you'll have to set the button.Enabled = false when the form initially loads since the textbox event won't fire on startup (true for all answers currently provided for your question).

Comment: string.IsNullOrEmpty is another option depending on the .NET Framework version you are targeting. And obviously, either the Enabled or Visible property can be used here.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        btn_cancel.Visible = false;
    else
        btn_cancel.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = sender as TextBox;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
    {
        btn_cancel.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        btn_cancel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

`sender.ToString()` will always return `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` you need to cast `sender` as `TextBox` and use the `Text` value for your null or empty check

Comment: This is unnecessary unless the OP is subscribing more than one textbox to the same event. If he isn't (which I assume), then he knows that `sender` is `textBox1`..

Comment: I was just showing his mistake about `sender.ToString()` , I don't really care how he uses it.

Answer (score 0):

try casting the sender to TextBox :

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)sender).Text))
```

Comment: This is unnecessary unless the OP is subscribing more than one textbox to the same event. If he isn't (which I assume), then he knows that `sender` is `textBox1`..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I think you missed the point, we're trying to show his mistake, as sa_ddam213 well said...

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
btn_cancel.Visible = textBox1.Text.Length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    string text = ((sender as TextBox) == null ? string.Empty : (sender as TextBox).Text);
    this.button1.Enabled = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) == false);
}
```

This doesn't assume the event source is a specific control and avoids an exception if by mistake it's attached to something that's not a `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (textBox2.Text == "") 
        {
            button5.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            button5.Enabled = true;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Please add some description explaining what you believe was the problem, and why this solution fixes it.